# "Error: 16" in Eclipse Run

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a simple program designed to correctly bin elements from a large text file and re-display them in an accessible way. When I run it in Eclipse, it appears to run fine (running a small test file reveals that no data is missing from the final bins), but the eclipse editor displays "Error: 16." Can someone tell me what this is? Thanks.

Edit:

Here is my complete console input. It is entirely test outputs during the run, with that error at the end:

0 4 7 1 0 2 3 4 6 7 6 7 6 7 6 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 95.80,
1.345345,2.3880140,2.43,

6.4.576,

74.5,34.58431,43.50,
67,23.080,
423,
456,

456.2,

6.5,2.8,
3153,29.6,

97.685,

56.821233,

745623482281234,7.64,

6788464,
86,

1.234234,

78.84321,

4.5688,

5672,

45.62,

41.5321,

3.45,56745848867,

4.5234523,
742,

528488,

34.58652,

2340852,243.52345,22.46246,4.35,

345.2347674567,

23452.14352435,

2.68488,2457537453,

2435.23452345,

4358,2.021564,

Error: 16

Comment: What else is on your console? please post it here.